# Как отправить письмо всем пользователям из БД?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть приложение на рельсах. При регистрации нового юзера отправляется письмо. Но мне бы хотелось наладить отправку по кнопке - чтобы при нажатии кнопки письмо было отправлено всем, кто есть в базе данных. Не понимаю, как реализовать такую кнопку

UsersController:

```
def send_mail
  @user = User.find( user_params)
  UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
end

def user_params
  params.permit(:name, :email, :login)
end
```

UserMailer

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://www.gmail.com'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

Кнопка отправки:

```
<a href="/send_mail">Отправить всем</a>
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  get '/send_mail' => "users#send_mail"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете прописать в контроллере:

```
def send_mail
  User.all.each do |user|
    UserMailer.welcome_email(user).deliver!
  end
end
```

Тогда ваше письмо будет отправляться абсолютно всем имеющимся пользователям.

Если нужно отправить определенным юзерам, используйте метод *where*

Например,

```
User.where("status = 'confirmed'").each do |user|
```